# Why does Spring @schedule annotation not run at exact times each day?

Tags: spring, spring-scheduled

I have a method annotated using spring schedule as follows:

`@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * *", zone = "Europe/Amsterdam")`.

What I have noticed is that the time this job runs sometimes differ. For example a snippet from the log:

```
2021-09-18T23:09:46,479 INFO  [ScheduledJob]
2021-09-19T22:00:00,005 INFO  [ScheduledJob] 
2021-09-20T23:07:40,760 INFO  [ScheduledJob]
```

I can understand if the execution time differs by seconds, but sometimes it differs by up to an hour

Why won't the `@scheduled` annotation not trigger at consistent times?

Comment: Do you have many other @Scheduled annotations in your code or is this the only one?

Comment: There are about 15 @Scheduled annotations.

Comment: Then it may be that the background thread pool handling task scheduling does not keep up and thus between the time the task is put on the queue and the time it is executed. Are those @Scheduled around the same time?

Comment: Different times...eg. some run like every 15mins, some run every hour and some run every midnight.

Comment: Then this might be it. Too many running jobs at the same time. Every 15 mins or every hour, it means they will at some point also start at midnight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try increasing the number of threads available as follows:
`spring.task.scheduling.pool.size = 5`

Or via JavaConfig:

```java
public class ThreadPoolTaskSchedulerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler(){
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(5);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("Whatever name you want to give it for debugging purposes");
        return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
    }
}
```

I used 5, but you might decide this is not enough and maybe try with more.